# No external mic input can be given to Laptop

Tags: microphone, audio, laptop

I have a ASUS A555LF laptop. I facing an issue with microphone, my laptop only detects in built mic but any other external mic source like headphones or condenser mic.

I used OBS as audio monitor for verification. Only noise from built in mic though laptop detects all the input devices like mic and headphones

I tried updating the driver, troubleshoot options and internal sound setting, drivers from ASUS website and realtek website but nothing worked.

I can hear audio on headphones

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell from such little information. It may be a routing issue, or a simple as a mis-matched pinout, or a phantom power issue… no way to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, here there is audio driver problem , for that am using usb sound card for to detect condenser mic, if am installed correct audio driver in pc while trouble shooting it showing in your system you installed Microsoft generic audio driver, after so many attempts like i tried to uninstall and reinstall still facing the issue , so i go for USB sound card now at least this card is  working fine am happy with that .